# window.print function call after form validating form in php

Tags: php

I have a problem, i want to print a a div after form validating and then submitting. Issue is, when call print.window function in submit button, it display print window without validating form fields.

`input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" name="submit" onclick="window.print()">`

while the div which to be print is in

`if($_POST['submit'])
    {
echo"print div here";
}`

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: JS is executed on the client. PHP on the server. Reevaluate your approach.

Comment: If you're validating the fields server-side then you'd have to print the window *after the response*, not *before*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print something after form validating and then submitting, you are supposed to do it in client side.

You can do something like this:

```
<form name="myForm" action="action.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post"> 
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then, validate form like this and print.

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    // validate your form here
    window.print();
}
</script>
```

Hope it helps.